# Could be iOS NFC background reading capability idle?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nfc

I know there could be cases such as

- the device has never been unlocked.
- a core NFC reader session is in progress.
- Apple Pay Wallet is in use.
- the camera is in use.
- airplane mode is enabled.

when NFC background tag reading is unavailable, **but could be possible to have background reading unavailable after couple of tag reads?**
I'm trying to reproduce the issue but it seems to happen randomly and after it is reproduced, **to re-enable the background reading I must open + close camera / lock + unlock the iphone**, and after that NFC background reading works well.

Note: issue reproduced on iphone 13 pro max

Comment: issue reproduced on couple of iPhones on client side, due to this issue we are trying to force NFC availability adding foreground reading within the app in order to scan NFC tags

Comment: update after 11 months...iPhones seems to freeze/turn off NFC background reading due to some reasons. So, in order to solve this we added NFC foreground reading and if we want to use background reading we force stop the NFC(turning on airplane mode, camera, etc) and after that it works fine :)